# A ball on a hemisphere.(Ignoring Rotation)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

I had come across this question from a STEP paper.

I was asked to find the displacement vector **r** of the particle after it is given a small displacement x from its initial position of A. $\theta$ maps the angular displacement from the line $OA$ to $OP$.The radius of this hemisphere is $a$. All surfaces are smooth and frictionless. The question assumes that the distance traveled by the hemisphere whilst the ball rolls is $-s$$\hat{i}$. Note that this $s$ changes as a function of $\theta$.

I got the following answer
$\vec{r}$= ($a\cos\theta$ $+$ $s$)$\hat{i}$ $-$ ($a\sin\theta$)$\hat{j}$. But the answer is given as $\vec{r}$= ($a\cos\theta$ $-$ $s$)$\hat{i}$ $-$ ($a\sin\theta$)$\hat{j}$. How did they get this answer as it is clear the particle won't stay with the hemisphere for a large $\theta$. (No attractive forces.) In turn, the particle would be separated by an additional distance of s making $\vec{r}$= ($a\cos\theta$ $+$ $s$)$\hat{i}$ $-$ ($a\sin\theta$)$\hat{j}$.

Comment: There are many Physics problems on the Internet related to your post such as [The motion of a ball moving down a circular path](https://web.archive.org/web/20200305174905id_/http://repositorio.unicamp.br/jspui/bitstream/REPOSIP/326001/1/000395409800006.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical JEE question involving concept of relative motion, solved it long ago.

There is a attractive force towards centre of hemisphere, that is the component of sphere's weight, also since the displacement is small we can consider sphere to be in contact with hemisphere all time.

The hemisphere is travelling left (obviously since sphere rolling towards right will push it in opposite direction)
The displacement of sphere relative to hemisphere will be
$$rcos\thetaî + (-s)î$$

We add the displacement vectors when motion is in opposite directions,

So obviously x component will be $$(rcos\theta-s)î$$

Regarding y component you are already correct.

Comment: "since the displacement is small.we can consider sphere to be in contact with hemisphere all time." When is this limit true till?

Comment: Perhaps,you have displacement vector, differentiate and find velocity vector, from that get relation for centrifugal force and put a constraint on it that it should be less than or equal to centripetal force provided by component of weight, you will get limit of $\theta$.

Answer (score -1):

By energy $$\frac{m}{2} (r  \ \dot \theta)^2 = m g (r-z) = m g r (1-\cos \theta)$$ calculate the centrifugal force $$ m r\dot \theta^2.$$ While the radial centrifugal force is smaller than the radial centripetal component of the weight $$K_r = m g \cos \theta$$ the points is moving on the circle.